# IF Function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a Google Sheet F Function to complete column C.

Column C should be Low, Mid, or High. This result is based on columns A and B:

Low = F/F

Mid = P/F or F/P

High = P/P

Your help with an F Function would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try this out in C2:

```
=index(switch(mmult(n(A2:B16="P"),{1;1}),2,"High",1,"Mid","Low"))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a simple multiple IF, like:

```
=IFS( A2 = "" , "" , not (A2 = B2), "Mid", A2 = "P" , "High" , A2 = "F" , "Low")
```

or derived as an array

```
= ARRAYFORMULA( IFS ( A2:A = "" , "" , not ( A2:A = B2:B ), "Mid", A2:A = "P" , "High" , A2:A = "F" , "Low" ))
```